# null is not an object (evaluating 'this.nativeCommandsModule.push')

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, viro-react

I am using WIX-React-Native-Navigation and while pushing a component in the stack I am getting this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQqDx.jpg)

One thing to say, I am using **Viro-React ARScene Navigation** ([Scene Navigation](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/scene-navigation)) in WIX-React-Native-Navigation.

Here's my code 
**index.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
var OpenDoor = require('./app/base')
import Stack from './app/navigation';

import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ViroSample', () => OpenDoor);

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: Stack
    }
  });
});
```

**navigation.js**

```
import { Navigation } from "react-native-navigation";

import Base from './base';
import Menu from './components/Menu/menu';

Navigation.registerComponent('Base', () => Base);
Navigation.registerComponent('Menu', () => Menu);


const Stack = {
    children: [{
            component: {
                name: 'Base'
            },
        }
    ]
};

export default Stack;
```

**base.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Alert,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import {ViroARSceneNavigator} from 'react-viro';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import APIKeys from './index';
import Camera from './components/Camera/camera';
import MenuButton from './components/Menu/menu_button';


class Base extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.navigateScreen = this.navigateScreen.bind(this);
    }

    navigateScreen(location) {
        Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
            component: {
                name: location
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ViroARSceneNavigator
                    initialScene = {{
                        scene: Camera
                    }}
                    apiKey = {APIKeys.ViroReact}
                    style = {styles.ar_scene}
                />
                <MenuButton navigation={this.navigateScreen}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
};

export default Base;
module.exports = Base;
```

Correct me, If I am wrong somewhere.

What I am doing is, creating an application where users can decorate home virtually with the help of Augmented Reality. The mobile app is created on React-Native while the library used for augmented reality is Viro-React.

So, When I want to navigate from One Screen to another, then while pushing component in the stack I am getting this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to push from Base to Location screen

Comment: If so Did u register the location screen

Comment: Yes, I am trying to push from base to location screen. While, yes I have registered the location screen. Its in navigation.js (talking about menu component)

Comment: Can u log that you are getting the componentId in Base component as well as in Navigation.push you have mentioned the name as location but in navigation.js there is no name like that.Can check by changing the name from location to menu in navigation.push and try